# How to get hand position on Hololens?

Tags: position, hololens

I have this script in order to get hand position with hololens, but it does not work and it gives me this error:
Errore  CS0123  Nessun overload per 'GetPosition' corrisponde al delegato 'Action'
Can someone help me ?

This is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.WSA.Input;


public class Hand : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }



    void Awake()
    {

        InteractionManager.InteractionSourcePressed += GetPosition; // No overload for 'GetPosition' corresponds to delegate 'Action<InteractionSourcePressedEventArgs>'

    }

    private void GetPosition(InteractionSourceState state)
    {
        Vector3 pos;
        if (state.sourcePose.TryGetPosition(out pos))
        {
            Debug.Log(pos);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error code pointed out that if you want to register for the `InteractionSourcePressed` input event, you should modify the callback function `GetPosition` to match the delegate of the `InteractionSourcePressed` event.

So, in this case, you can refer to the following code to fix this issue:

```
private void GetPosition(InteractionSourceState state)
```

=>

```
private void GetPosition(InteractionSourcePressedEventArgs args)
```

More information please see:[Windows-specific APIs (XR.WSA.Input)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/gestures-and-motion-controllers-in-unity#windows-specific-apis-xrwsainput)

Comment: Thank you very much!!! Do you perhaps know what package i need to import on unity (unity 2018) in order to make it feasible ?